# Linux dialog user input directly to variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, dialog

I am building a interactive bash script and I have been using whiptail for input and message boxes. However the infoboxes will not always work. (Works on my active server but not on my VM. Same Ubuntu 14.04 accessed with Putty in windows)

I am trying to switch to dialog but the code I was using with whiptail to output to a variable rather than a file does not seem to work in dialog.

```
UNAME=$(whiptail--inputbox "Enter the user you want your scripts to run as. (Case sensitive, Must exist)" 10 50 --title "System Username" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

I tried changing whiptail to dialog and I get a box and can enter and submit data but then the variable is not set. I got this from another forum and there was no real description of whats actually happening here. All I know is it sets the variable with the input data rather than what is normally output to stderr.

Comment: The bit at the end is playing output redirection games. I'm not sure why that was necessary. (I'm assuming `whiptail--inputbox` is just a typo here and not in your actual script?)

Comment: Yes, that is a typo. Your right, it is redirecting outputs. If theres an alternative that does not require writing to a file I am interested.

Comment: Is there a file in that example? I don't see one. I also don't see what would be writing/opening fd 3.

Comment: That does not write to anything. But when I tried it with dialog it dident work. Turned out dialog does not like the title after the widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dialog appears to be sensitive to option ordering. Put the `--title` option *before* the `--inputbox` option and it should work (at least it does here).

Comment: I was actually answering my own question with that. Thanks!

Comment: Sure - as noted in the [manual](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT), most of the common options are reset before each widget.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks for the information. Not the most obvious place for that information though (unless it also appears other places/etc. I don't really use `dialog` ever).